# Camel component not see datasource

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-jdbc

Here my java config(Spring 3.2.4, camel 2.13.4), which create camelContext and dataSource

```
@Configuration
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = "some.package.here")
 public class BeansConfig {
 @Bean
 public DataSource dataSource(){
    DataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    ((DriverManagerDataSource)dataSource).setDriverClassName(driver);
    ((DriverManagerDataSource)dataSource).setUrl(url);
    ((DriverManagerDataSource)dataSource).setUsername(username);
    ((DriverManagerDataSource)dataSource).setPassword(password);
     return dataSource;
}
 @Bean
 public CamelContext camelContext() throws Exception {
    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    return camelContext;
}
}
```

And i have junit4 test class

```
    @RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = BeansConfig.class,loader = CamelSpringDelegatingTestContextLoader.class)
    public class CamelTestSpring {
      @Autowired
      private CamelContext camelContext;
      @Autowired
      private DataSource dataSource;


      @Before
      public void setUpContext() throws Exception {
        camelContext.getProperties().put(Exchange.LOG_DEBUG_BODY_MAX_CHARS, "1500");
        camelContext.addRoutes(routeBuilder());
        producerTemplate = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
        Endpoint endpoint = camelContext.getEndpoint("direct:inSql");
        producerTemplate.setDefaultEndpoint(endpoint);
        camelContext.start();
       }
       @After
       public void cleanUpContext() throws Exception {
         camelContext.stop();
       }

    public RouteBuilder routeBuilder() throws Exception {
     return new RouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:inSql").to("sql:select * from dual");
      }
     };
    }

    @Test
    public void testDatasourse() {
    producerTemplate.sendBody("test");
  }
}
```

My problem is that camelContext not see dataSource when i run route, although dataSource exist and inject properly. I tried  route `from("direct:inSql").to("sql:select * from dual?dataSource=#dataSource");` but this not help.

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: dataSource of type: javax.sql.DataSource
```

What my mistake and how solve that?

Comment: It sure would be nice if someone would answer this, or if it was properly documented.